# Share folder including Eclipse workspace with Git between WinXP and Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, git, workspace

I have this general project folder of mine which includes a variety of stuff: text, images, binary files etc. I want and need to keep this project in version control under git, so if I mess up something I can revert to a previous version of all files.

One thing inside this project is an Eclipse IDE Java workspace with all it's contents.

My questions is, how can I share this general project including the Eclipse workspace between my Mac OS X and WinXP computers so that pushes and pulls would go as smoothly as possible?

As it is now, whenever I push from e.g. OSX to remote repository and pull from there to my XP machine, the classpaths and stuff goes all wrong again and I need to put down quite an effort to sort things up.

Comment: It is a bad idea to share workspaces between different versions of Eclipse.  As of 2016 write Maven modules instead as this allows easy regeneration of a project on a new machine while keeping the metadata outside of your shared file tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set up the machines to ignore any OS specific information

this can be acomplished with putting a file named .gitignore in the root of the working directory of the repository.

in .gitignore

```
/path/not/to/share/*
```

Comment: This worked out well eventually even though there was pretty much to ignore that did not work on both platforms. 
Checking out to a new platform requires some additional work now, but that shouldn't happen all too often.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "the stuff" (may be [exporting preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951509/maintaining-a-common-set-of-eclipse-preferences/951824#951824) and re-importing them after the git pull could help.

Regarding the paths, I would definitively recommend configuring your project with [**linked directories**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300328/eclipse-attach-source-javadoc-to-a-library-via-a-local-property/300346#300346) and a path variable for linked resources: that variable is set per eclipse installation and would remain valid for a given machine.