# Setting up Eclipse with dropbox

Tags: eclipse, dropbox

I know some one has asked similar question, but the answer is not what i am looking for.

Here is my situation: I have two computers, one is window 7, the other one is Macbook air.

When I am in school, I use the air to write code and I want write my code at home on window 7.

any genius come up with a solution that I don't have to import the project every time taking

advantage of dropbox?  providing detailed solution is the best.  just wanna make it clear, I

am using Eclipse just for Java.

Comment: so what happens when simply have the workspace as a dropbox folder?

Comment: before  asking  this question, i read some posts, that keeping saying we can't just put the workspace as a folder in dropbox because there is a folder called .metadata. we need to take care of. and also Mac and pc are different operating system. we should not selective this folder. but the instruction in that post is not very clear, so i am asking it again

Comment: try setting up a SVN server somewhere (or github)

Comment: what do you mean by SVN Server ?  can you explain it in detailed steps ?

Comment: using SVN Server seems like a more complicated solution for me.  mainly, I just want my code available on two computer without manually  sync.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935528/sharing-eclipse-directory-on-dropbox-between-windows-and-mac-os-x?rq=1

Comment: "so i am asking it again" - This is not allowed on stackoverflow. If the same question exists but just has not enough answers, add a bounty to the existing question. If you have a different question, clearly indicate what is different in your case and why you can't user the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have the same "problem" but there is a simple solution.Create a folder in DropBox as your `project path`, While in school, you can just import it directly from the folder, and work on it.When ever you save, it get saved in the DropBox folder.But remember, while importing, do not select the `copy project into workspace` option.Also remember to close eclipse on one computer before opening the project in another.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed steps ?

Comment: Create a folder in `DropBox` say `...\Dropbox\project` on your computer at home then when ever you need to use the project in school, just import it from the `...\Dropbox\project` folder( make sure not to select the "copy project into workspace option when importing else what ever changes you make in the imported version will not be persisted in Dropbox) When you are done working with it on either computer, make sure to close eclipse before opening in another.If you follow these steps, when even you open eclipse on either computer, it just loads the project from `...\Dropbox\project`

Comment: so we need to manually import a project as an exiting project after we  switch computer?

Comment: Exactly.In the Dropbox folder, the files are the same.

Comment: You lost me at "remember to close eclipse" lol

Answer (score 3):

Another way to make this easy for you , with the use of rapidsvn see the information on above link.[enter link description here](http://www.rapidsvn.org/index.php/OnlineHelp%3aContents)

Comment: Thank you for the option, However, it seems like a more complicated solution. I am watching some video to set up SVN. If you have some good guide, please provide. (I am only using it for Java)

Comment: after watching some videos, i have a idea of it. but SVN is something for big project or or a team, If No body knows how to do it just using dropbox,  I will try SVN.

Comment: i think it's better solution, but as u told it is somewhat big

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/EclipseIntroduction.html#workspace shows how you can set the workspace to a different location.  You would just select a folder in Dropbox instead of on a usb stick like the guide shows.
When syncing with Dropbox, beware of syncing conflicts if you are trying to use Eclipse on both computers at the same time or Dropbox hasn't yet finished synced all the changes.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed steps ? the link you provided is not quit what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter that there's source code in some directory that happens to be tied to Dropbox, so upload that particular folder to Dropbox.

However.  There is ***much*** pain ahead of you if you elect to go that route.

Cloud-based file hosting services aren't the same as a revision system, which can be used to not only keep track of all of your source code files, but also give you history into what you've changed.

The best part about this is - there's a plethora of them to choose from, including but not limited to [GitHub](https://www.github.com) and [Bitbucket](https://www.bitbucket.org).  Further, they **all** can be pushed to, and subsequently, pulled from, just about anywhere.