# Are eclipse C++ IDE Workspaces fully compatible with all IDE platform versions? (Linux, iOS, Windows...)

Tags: eclipse, cross-platform, compatibility, workspace

Are workspaces created by eclipse for c++ with one OS fully compatible with the same IDE but on another OS or will I have to deal with some kind of issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, workspaces won't just work if you change platforms and nothing else due to the locations of libraries, compilers, etc. being different on different platforms.

Another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6883280/2600883) explains how you can use Dropbox's selective sync to keep the platform specific files separate from everything else.  Many popular version control systems ([git](http://git-scm.com/), [svn](https://subversion.apache.org/)) have an "ignore" functionality that will keep platform specific stuff from being shared.

Comment: I'll take a look at Dropbox. Looks like that will do the trick. I'm used to free svns, but i don't know any used with iOS which is my problem now.