# How to set the default workspace settings of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I develop C and Python using eclipse (using CodeBench, which is eclipse). My main job is embedded development and i have to support multiple products, so I make extensive use of the workspace feature of eclipse.

I have 3-5 main workspaces, each with 5-10 eclipse projects.

If I have to support an older version of a firmware, I checkout the Tag and create a new workspace. Because of company policy, I can't check in my workspace settings into svn/git, so it uses the default settings (no line numbers, layout, ...).

Is there a possibility to 'define actual settings as default for new workspaces'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining a common set of Eclipse preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951509/maintaining-a-common-set-of-eclipse-preferences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export your preferences from a workspace in to a file and then import them in another workspace.

Use 'File > Export > General > Preferences' to export the preferences.

Use 'File > Import > General > Preferences' to import.

Comment: which is a valid workaround, thank you for the solution. But I will wait for a answer to my question before accepting yours.