# How to improve the performance of Eclipse IDE under QNX6

Tags: java, performance, eclipse

We are running Eclipse over QNX6 in a VMWare environment and it's very slow.

Eclipse is launched like this:

```
/usr/qnx630/host/qnx6/x86/usr/qde/eclipse/eclipse -data /root//workspace

/usr/qnx630/host/qnx6/x86/usr/qde/eclipse/jre/bin/pvm -pri 13 -ts 4 -gs 4 
-gcperiod 500 -cs 512000 -nojit -numregs 64 -maxmem 256M -Djava.version 
-classpath /usr/qnx630/host/qnx6/x86/usr/qde/eclipse/startup.jar 
org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main -os qnx -ws photon -arch x86 -showsplash 
/usr/qnx630/host/qnx6/x86/usr/qde/eclipse/eclipse -showsplash 600 -exitdata 
/usr/qnx630/host/qnx6/x86/usr/qde/eclipse/eclipse -exitdata /tmp/eclipse_25b034 
-data /root//workspace
```

Any ideas to make it faster? Like turning off some features, tuning the gc, general ideas not specific to QNX or VMWare...

Comment: take a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957488/eclipse-optimizations/979350#979350

Comment: What exactly is 'too slow' - workbench responsiveness or real processing (like rebuilding the workspace)? Does increasing the memory to 512M help?

Comment: Yeah I mean workbench responsiveness. I'm taking a look at the other question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bump up the max memory (maxmem, or Xmx) to at least 512M - we run with 512M to 1024M because Eclipse is fairly heavy weight, which is to be expected with all the plugins and features. 
Also, I would uninstall any end-user plugins you are not using.

Answer (score 2):

The -maxmem 256M argument looks suspiciuos.  Try bumping it to 512M or more.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is also really slow if you're running a gargantuan project. Where I am we have a large core library that all the (much smaller) subprojects require. Rather than keeping that open, I just build it as a jar and link to the jar when I work on the satellite projects. Eclipse is *much* faster with 100 java files than with 1000+, even on a local box with plenty of memory.