# How to change Eclipse run script in QNX6?

Tags: eclipse, qnx

Related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207306/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-eclipse-ide-under-qnx6), we want to change the eclipse run command.
I found that eclipse can run executing the script:

```
/usr/qnx630/host/qnx6/x86/usr/bin/qde.sh
```

But the startup configuration is not written there. The only thing the script does is executing the file:

```
/usr/qnx630/host/qnx6/x86/usr/qde/eclipse/eclipse
```

This file is a binary which ends calling another one with all the startup parameters for Eclipse.

So my question is: where can I find and change those parameters?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first look at the [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-eclipse-34-jvm-settings#144349) file to check if your startup configuration is not better expressed there.
(that is one element for having a [quicker eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse/316535#316535))

In your case, it should be at:

```
/usr/qnx630/host/qnx6/x86/usr/qde/eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

If it is not there, you could create it. It would be detected by eclipse during launch.