# Eclipse .metadata/workspace

Tags: eclipse

I started storing my projects in my git folder instead the main workspace and importing in.

My question is can I backup that .metadata folder in the workspace to keep my settings just in case?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently .workspace is not portable. However, since you're doing a back-up, everything should work if you have the same software installed as when you made the backup. Same Eclipse version, compilers, web servers, languages installed (PHP, Python, etc.) and same installation paths. Also, various settings can be exported using File->Export->General->Preferences/C/C++ Project settings/etc.

See: 
[Eclispe workspace backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657884/eclispe-workspace-backup)

[Backup Eclipse settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701544/backup-eclipse-settings)

Answer (score 0):

The workspace (which is basically just the .metadata directory) is not intended or designed to be shared. Backing it up might work, but I haven't tried it. However, you can easily export your settings using File > Export and then store that file anywhere you want. Then it's easy to import the settings via File > Import later (into any workspace).
Also, keep in mind that many settings can be configured on a per-project basis. If you do that, they're stored in a file in the project and thus can be checked into your source control system like git, cvs, etc.