# How to automatically import eclipse editor preferences that were previously exported?

Tags: eclipse, default, preferences

I have a similar problem to this guy: [Importing/Exporting Project Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881655/importing-exporting-project-preferences), but my problem is worse, I need to create a new workspace (i.e. new base directory) for every program or version that I work on.  I have some common preferences (formatter, font size, etc) that I have exported to a file, which I then import every time I create a new workspace, but would like to skip the step of manually importing the .epf file.  Has anybody seen an easy way to automate this?

EDIT: to help potential respondents answer the question, here is my workflow for handling a bug patch.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong in general that you could correct (since I've only been using Eclipse for a couple of years and tend to prefer emacs so I haven't spent a lot of time learning new Eclipse features)?

1. Create new directory for the workspace.
2. Start Eclipse editor and open clean workspace.
3. Check out a CVS directory containing .psf files for the various programs (necessary because of a pre-existing CVS tree structure that does not play nice with Eclipse).
4. Use team import on the .psf file associated with the program I'm working on to pull in the necessary projects.
5. Switch all projects to the branch tag associated with the release in question.
6. Work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy your original workspace. Easy, reliable, but will also copy all your projects.

Comment: This seems to be the cheapest solution.  I created a prototype workspace directory by setting all of the preferences, and then I wrote a small script to install this directory in the correct path using cp -r.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: Sometimes us Software Engineers try to go for the cleanest most elegant solution when a quick fix will do just fine :)

Answer (score 4):

I think that Workspace Mechanic solves all your problems.
http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/

Comment: Workspace Mechanic should be part of core Eclipse.