# Turn off spell checking in Eclipse for good

Tags: eclipse

Every time I create a new workspace in Eclipse I have to turn off the spell checking via Preferences. (Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling->Enable Spell Checking)

This is very irritating. How do I turn off the spell checking for good? I.e. the spell checker is disabled when I create a new workspace and I can turn it on should I want to use it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not a perfect fix, but you can copy existing workspace preferences into any workspace. I keep a separate `.epf` (Eclipse preferences file, I guess) that I just import into every new workspace I create:

*File → Import... → General → Preferences → Next > From preference file*

[image: screenshot]

#### Related

- [Importing/Exporting Project Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881655/importing-exporting-project-preferences)

Comment: Thanks. This is what really annoys me with Eclipse. Somebody has decided what the default Preferences are and there is no way for us to change them. So we are left with this quite complicated maneuver every time we open up a new workspace.

Comment: It's not great, but it's not terrible. I actually keep that `.epf` in my Dropbox so I can share preferences across a couple different computers and OSes, and it works well enough for me.

Comment: this isnt an answer

Comment: @PhilipRego As commented this is far from a perfect solution but it's the best anyone seems to have found, at least at the time of writing, six and a half years ago. Feel free to suggest an edit or post your own answer if you have something more useful to contribute.

Comment: It's not an answer because you don't mention how to "Turn off spell checking in Eclipse"

Comment: @PhilipRego I think you may have partially misread the original question. The OP knows how to turn off spell checking; those steps are described in the question. You might have noticed that [another answer lists those same steps and is called out as not answering the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17837426/139010) in the comments below. The nuance here is that that setting doesn't disable spell checking, **permanently.** And, as I commented, if you have something to add to this ancient thread, please post an answer or suggest an edit. Better to light a candle than curse the darkness.

Comment: I think answers should be complete. If I just followed your answer spell checking would still be enabled. I'm not saying your solution is bad, just that it's incomplete without reading the original post. As someone who uses Stack for quick solutions I don't like having to read the full question, I read just the title and a solution.

Answer (score 20):

Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling
Uncheck the box "Enable spell checking"

Comment: How it is correct when the question asks how to turn it off for good?

Comment: It's Window->Preferences not Preferences and that doesnt even work

Comment: That's meant to work but it doesn't after restarting Eclipse. So this answer is simply wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There are some ways for sharing preferences, but it doesn't come with the platform.
The one I use is now available as an attachment to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334016 or more particular as attachment https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=196866

Install into your Eclipse.
Then you can export selected preferences to an .epf file.
Also add a preference (!) in Preferences > General > Common Preferences which will share your settings across newly created workspaces.

I use this all the time and though it is not perfect, it does save a lot of effort in keeping my preferences aligned across workspaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing Java code, Window -> Preferences -> Java -> JDT Spelling

Comment: Thanks! That did it for me. Also got rid of the annoying spell checker with Scala