# Eclipse: how to selectively disable spell check in certain comments

Tags: java, eclipse, spell-checking

I am using Eclipse, Kepler version.

How do I disable the spell checking inside comments?

I do see "Window | Preferences | General | Editors | Text Editors | Spelling", but this sheet has no option about disabling spell checking inside comments.

Ideally, I would like to disable spell checking for a specific comment.

In other places spell checking comments can be useful.

Additionally, I did see the other referenced solution, which I am using and did use, but I did not want to disable spell checking for good. I wanted to turn off spell checking in certain situations but leave it on for others. That was addressed in a comment, so if the negative vote was because my question was addressed elsewhere, then it was not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn off spell checking in Eclipse for good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295066/turn-off-spell-checking-in-eclipse-for-good)

Comment: I do NOT want to disable disable spell checking for good. I like spell checking. Additionally, what makes you all think that I did not use Google?

Comment: Also, the option mentioned, I indicated in my question. I used "|" instead of "-->", which the referenced issue mentioned.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to disable/enable spell checking for certain areas. You can try to write your own Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Not worth the time and effort, at the moment. I figured this question was obvious, so I thought that I ask it, as I am new to Eclipse. The answer is that there is no way to selectively turn off spell check selectively, except globally. I can accept that.

Comment: A useful question for sure. Personally I would like to have spell checking turned off inside `@{code }` fragments - I typically use variable names there which more often than not fail to be proper words

Comment: It is too bad this does not exist.  I have a couple of two letter acronyms used in strings that get flagged by the spell checker. I don't want to add them to my use dictionary because I only use them in one place, but I don't like the warnings either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a way to turn off spell checking for a comment. You've either got words in there or you don't. You can, however, add what's been flagged as a misspelling to your own user dictionary, in which case that particular word will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable spell checking:

```
Window->Preferences :: General->Editor->Text Editors->Spelling,
uncheck the box "Enable spell checking"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the spell-checked comment, then scroll down to and click "Disable spell checking".

Comment: This option is the same as globally.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding. I don't see why you would need spell checking outside of comments.

Comment: I did not write Eclipse, so I am not sure of all the spell checking areas. There are strings, comments, and whatever else. I was just interested in one particular comment. The answer is that there is no way to selectively turn off a comment, just globally as mentioned in the other article, which I already found on my own and mentioned in my question.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I read as something along the lines of "specifically for comments". You can ignore certain words, which may or may not yield similar results to what you want to do. Anyway, sorry for the mix up.