# disable spell check in eclipse for javadoc only

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Is it possible to disable spell check in eclipse for javadoc only?

[image]

Comment: [Seems Answer is no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983776/eclipse-how-to-selectively-disable-spell-check-in-certain-comments) but you can add them to your dictionary ;P

Comment: Ahh, missed that, thx